# Need automatic reload values from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem for getting automatic values from the database.
Using PHP CodeIgnitor
I am using a testimonial in my home page that are loaded from the student table of my database. I know how to display the whole testimonials or a particular testimonials. But please help me to automatically reload and show each testimonial after 10 seconds. Here is my code:

**Controller**:

```
public function index()

{
    $data=$this->data;
    $data['news']=$this->stthomasmodel->latestNews();
    $data['testimonials']=$this->stthomasmodel->testimonials();

    $this->load->view('index.php',$data);

}
```

**Model**:

```
//Function for retreiving Testimomnials from the database
public function testimonials()
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT testimonials FROM student");
    return $query->result();
}
```

**View**:

```
 $i=count($testimonials); for ($x = 0; $x <$i; $x++)    echo
 $testimonials[$x]->testimonials."<br>";
```

Please suggest me an idea.
Thanks

Comment: Use a Javascript setInterval on html page and set a Jquery Ajax call on 10 seconds?

Comment: I am completely new in thios area. Would you suggest me a sample code?

Comment: setInterval example -> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: SO How should I use it with Codeignitor in the above case?

Comment: you can put it inside the html code of the page.

Comment: But I don't want to show it as a alert.  For example: I have the First testimonial as "This school is good". Then the second testimonials as "School facilities are outstanding". I wanna show  "This school is good" when somebody enters the index page and it should automatically replaced by " School facilities are outstanding" after 10 seconds..   Help plz...

Comment: Please listen to me. Set Interval Can run something each time (example 10 seconds). Now As for Something you can run an Ajax call to another page and then replace your data how needed.

Comment: Finally It worked.. Cheers.........

Comment: @JinsonVarghese please share your solution and mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to use Ajax jquery.
Load student data specific div such as div id=studentlist. 
you may use load or get method to retrieve student data ub studentlist div
here get and load both are jquery function

Or you may just use HTML meta tag to reload the page after given period of time

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

This page auto refresh after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

use jquery setInterval..

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(get_data, 1000);
  });
  function get_data()
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'controller/method' ?>",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data.result);
      }
   });
  }
</script>
```

if you want u can use load method instead of ajax..